# 76% of the RAM usage on my server is TEXT_MIX_PAGE in tempdb. What does this indicate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory, tempdb, buffer-pool

I quite like dbatools, so I gave `Get-DbaDbMemoryUsage` ([docs here](https://docs.dbatools.io/Get-DbaDbMemoryUsage.html)) a try on my test SQL Server 2019 server. Specifically, I ran this

```powershell
Get-DbaDbMemoryUsage -SqlInstance [MyServer] -IncludeSystemDbs |
Select Database, PageType, PercentUsed |
Where PercentUsed -ne 0 |
Format-Table
```

The idea of the command is that it shows what percentage of your server's RAM is being used by what type of pages in each of your databases.

When I read my results, I was shocked to discover that 76% of my RAM usage on my server is TEXT_MIX_PAGE in tempdb. What does this indicate? For what it's worth, said server was very quiet at the time I ran this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The idea of the command is that it shows what percentage of your server's RAM is being used by what type of pages in each of your databases.

It'll show you what *type* of pages are in the ***buffer pool*** for each databases (which is no different than querying `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors` yourself). While the buffer pool is typically the largest consumer of memory for the instance, it is **not the only consumer** and moreover the contents of the buffer pool are constantly *in flux* based on what items are needed.

Querying the DMV (which is all the dbatools item does) will give you a snapshot in time of what I explained above, but is the data actionable or helpful in any way?

It depends on what question you are attempting to answer. If the question is about the buffer pool usage, then I guess it *sort* of answers the question, though I don't know many times that question would ever need to be asked.

If the question was about what is being used for the database, that will change based on workload, customers of the database, and needs. It may very well hit some tables hard during one day, answering questions about mailing addresses, and the next do something completely different when generating a report about the number of items sold that hour. I don't see how the type or number of page types are helpful in this situation.

There are more questions that could be asked, but none that I can think of which really make this data *worth* collecting. Moreover, if you're interested in the makeup of the data layout in the database, there are other storage engine based DMVs which could be more useful, such as looking at LOB data usage. How that's more helpful? I don't know, depends on the question. It could be somewhat helpful to identify data objects that need refactored, and that's a stretch.